# Liquibase: How to set default TimeStamp to 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html) seems to support it

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0
);
```

I do this with Liquibase as,

```
<column name="updated_at" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValue="0">
</column>
```

But when I run this, I see

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL INSERT INTO PUBLIC.network (id, network_id, name, display_name) VALUES (0, 0, 'Yahoo! Ad Network', 'YAN-US'): Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "0"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.network (id, network_id, name, display_name) VALUES (0, 0, 'Yahoo! Ad Network', 'YAN-US') [22007-178]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:61)
```

Comment: If this happens at runtime while inserting something liquibase has obviously already created the table. Did you check the mysql DB on how the table was created? Maybe you can find a difference to how liquibase created it and how it looks like when you create it manually? 
Also, what does the whole PUBLIC.network table look like? How is it connected to the t1 table where you created the TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Yes, looking at the error I would be suspicious that the table was created as a DATETIME rather than a TIMESTAMP